# C# HttpWebRequest and Javascript based form submittion actions

Tags: c#, javascript, webrequest, webresponse

I am trying to make a simple web crawler as a learning experience and I have hit a wall. I am able to set cookies, get cookies, and keep cookies over a session however I am now stuck when attempting to submit login information. Looking at the source of the website I see that the login form has a username and password field with a submit button who's action is a javascript call.

If it was a POST call I wouldn't have a problem but I can't figure out how to handle logging in using HttpWebRequest. Is it possible? If not how can I go about doing this? (Can I?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because it is a javascript call doesn't mean you can't do a POST. I would read the javascript and see what it does, then do something similar.

Comment: After reviewing the javascript they end up making a call to DWSEngine for some Ajax. I have looked but can't find the actual post url.

Comment: I would try doing it in a browser and having fiddler up. That should give you what the javascript ends up doing, you just have to craft a similar request